# Does a photo with two Saturn V's on launch pad 39A and 39B exist?

Tags: history, saturn-v

There is a [beautiful photo](https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/image_feature_1179.html) of two Space Shuttles on launch pads 39A and 39B. [Apollo 10 was the only Saturn V launch from pad 39B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy_Space_Center_Launch_Complex_39B#Apollo_program). Were either Apollo 9 or Apollo 11 close enough in time to have two Saturn Vs occupying both pads? If yes, does a photo exist?

[image: Saturn V and Saturn 1B]

*A Saturn V with Skylab and a Saturn 1B with the first crew (source: [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/content/40-years-ago-skylab-paved-way-for-international-space-station))*

[image: Atlantis and Endeavour]

*Atlantis and Endeavour (source: [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/image_feature_1179.html))*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No.**

From the [Apollo 10 preparation timeline](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap10fj/as10-prep.html), the spacecraft was rolled out to 39B on March 11, 1969.

Apollo 9 launched on March 3, 1969, so there can not be a photo of the two launch vehicles both rolled out to 39B and 39A.

https://www.nasa.gov/feature/50-years-ago-apollo-11-rolls-out-to-the-launch-pad Has this picture of Apollo 11 rolling out to 39A, with the text:

> On May 20, 1969, while Apollo 10 was on its way to the Moon, the Saturn V that carried Apollo 11 on its historic journey took the first steps toward its ultimate destination.

Apollo 10 launched on May 18. Thus, **no such photo can exist**.

Comment: A sad truth, missed a great photo opportunity by two days...

Comment: Great answer! That could be slightly improved by not burying the lede. Maybe state up front that the answer is no before explaining how you know that?

Comment: The lede is pretty clear: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oSec.png

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys do you mind to add the launch data of Apollo 10 in? Or I can do it, if that's ok.

Comment: Edit away. I miss when that was the normal on SE.

Comment: It seems possible that the Apollo 11 Saturn V was deliberately not rolled out prior to Apollo 10 launching, in order to protect the Apollo 11 Saturn V in case of unplanned rapid disassembly of the Apollo 10 rocket.